# Capturing warning message into a variable in RR

Tags: r

I have a function `draw_plot()` that takes in a data frame and other parameters(through the ellipsis) and simply returns a line plot.

```
draw_plot <- function(data, ...){
  plot <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))
  plot <- plot + do.call("geom_line", c(list(...)))
  return(plot)}


data <- tibble::tibble(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y = c(5,6,7,8,9,10))
draw_plot(data, test = 2, wrong = "")
```

If I call the function as above, with parameters with key values which the `geom_line()` function doesn't recognize, it returns a warning saying 'Ignoring unknown parameters: test, wrong'.

I am hoping to improve the function to facilitate more parameters, and other ggplot geoms. (ex: draw_plot(data, stat, ...)) The stat parameter will not be valid for `geom_line()`. Therefore I want to capture the original warning message and append 'stat' to it. ex: 'Ignoring unknown parameters: test, wrong, stat'

To do this, is there any way that I can capture this particular warning message into a variable? p.s. I am trying to stick to base R to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can capture the warning message -

```
draw_plot <- function(data, ...){
  plot <- ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))
  plot <- tryCatch(plot + do.call("geom_line", c(list(...))), 
                   warning = function(w) {
      if(grepl('Ignoring unknown parameters', w$message)) 
        wmsg <<- as.character(w$message)
      return(NULL)
    })
  if(exists('wmsg')) print(wmsg)
  return(plot)
}
draw_plot(data, test = 2, wrong = "")
draw_plot(data)
```

Comment: Would this still throw any other warning messages as is, or does it catch them and ignore them. I want everything to function as is, but only the 'Ignore unknown parameters to be captured and manually handled thereafter

Comment: Yes, this throws away other warning messages. It will only capture `'Ignoring unknown parameters'` messages.

Comment: Is there any way to still include other errors/warnings etc. and only capture 'Ignoring unknown parameters'? Even in cases where the function might give out multiple warnings - I want to print out all other warnings and only check for 'Ignoring unknown parameters' and handle it manually

Comment: If you remove the `if` condition in `warning` then it will capture all the warning messages.